# Difference between Encoding.Default.GetBytes and Using MemoryStream

Tags: c#, xml, encoding

```
XDocument xDocumentObject = XDocument.Parse("<Test>"+
            "<elementx id='1'  att='aaa' />" +
            "<elementx id='2'  att='bbb' />" +
            "</Test>");
```

What is the difference between :

1)

```
byte[] xmlBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(xDocumentObject.ToString());
```

AND

2)

```
byte[] xmlBytes;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
   xDocumentObject.Save(ms);
   xmlBytes = ms.ToArray();
}
```

What is "Default" encoding in (1) and what is the encoding used in (2) and which is the preferred way?

Comment: completely depends on xDocumentObject, but as you dont provide any input for that an answer is not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case you are using the encoding for the operating system's current ANSI code page to convert the string to a byte array. The string represents the XML document generated by the `XDocument` instance and converted to a byte array. In .NET all strings are Unicode encoded.

In the second example the encoding of the [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) is used. So for example if you have the following XML `<?xml encoding="utf-8"?>` it will use UTF-8. The [Declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.declaration.aspx) property allows you to specify the encoding being used:

```
XDocument xDocumentObject = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"), 
    new XElement(
        "Test",
        new XElement("elementx", new XAttribute("id", "1"), new XAttribute("att", "aaa")), 
        new XElement("elementx", new XAttribute("id", "2"), new XAttribute("att", "bbb"))
    )
);
```

or:

```
XDocument xDocumentObject = XDocument.Parse(
    @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" standalone=""yes""?>
    <Test>
        <elementx id=""1"" att=""aaa"" />
        <elementx id=""2"" att=""bbb"" />
    </Test>"
);
```

allows you to specify UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: wrong, if you use the XmlDocument.ToString() function, you just get the bytes of the string "System.Xml.XmlDocument"

Comment: @user287107, you are correct. Thanks for pointing this out. I will update my answer.

Comment: @user1422578, I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Darin - which is the preferred way? If I haven't specified the encoding in the Xml in the 2nd case, what would be the encoding used?

Comment: The second is the preferred way. If you don't specify an encoding, when you are writing to a `MemoryStream`, UTF-8 will be used by default.

Comment: Then looks like `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xDocumentObject.ToString());` would also do the job.

Comment: No, it will not do the job. You could get wrong results. For example if you specified some different encoding in the XML declaration and your system's default encoding is different you will end up with wrongly encoded byte array.

Answer (score 1):

1)
you get the full name of the class, here "System.Xml.XmlDocument" encoded with the default codepage (similar to ascii, 1byte /char on my computer)

2)
just take a look at the documentation "The value of the encoding attribute is taken from the XmlDeclaration.Encoding property" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/z5250dbd.aspx
the property has a default value: "If an encoding attribute is not included, UTF-8 encoding is assumed when the document is written or saved out." 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.xml.xmldeclaration.encoding.aspx